# Передача заголовков письма в команду . Maildrop or Postfix

Tags: postfix

Подскажите как я могу передать заголовки новых принятых писем в команду используя postfix или maildrop с фильтром по адресу получателя. Нигде не могу найти подобное. И получится ли обходиться без файлов в случае c maildrop.

Вот псевдокод для .filtermail:

```
if (/^To: *auto@domain\.com$/)
   to this_mail | python ~/script.py command
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так: принятое письмо сливается во временный файл, там его можно всячески обработать - добавить заголовки, проверить антивирусом, сохранить в архиве и т.д. - затем письмо отправляется дальше.

```
master.cf:
127.0.0.1:smtp inet n - - - - smtpd -o content_filter=
10.20.30.40:smtp inet n - - - - smtpd -o content_filter=filter:dummy
filter  unix    - n n - 3 pipe flags=Rq user=nobody argv=/etc/postfix/filter.sh ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Подробнее: запускаются 2 smtpd процесса. Первый слущает реальный IP адрес и имеет в опциях конект-фильтр. Он собственно его и запускает после приема тела письма. Второй слушает 127.0.0.1 и не имеет контент-фильтра - это для отправки письма дальше.

Теперь пишем сам фильтр:

```
filter.sh:
#!/bin/sh

# не забываем удалить за собой временные файлы
trap "rm -f /tmp/in.$$ /tmp/kav.$$ /tmp/clam.$$ " 0 1 2 3 15
cd /tmp
cat >in.$$ || { echo Cannot save mail to file; exit 75; }
chmod 0666 in.$$

Делаем что хотим с телом письма, оно в файле in.$$
отправляем его дальше

$SENDMAIL -f $@ < in.$$
exit $?
```

Внутри filter.sh можно также анализировать какие-то свои политики, например по ключевым словам, вложениям или по результатам работы антивируса и модифицировать адрес получателя (в карантин, в СБ) и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

можно воспользоваться универсальным, ещё *unix*-овым механизмом, частью которого является файл `/etc/aliases`.

пример.

добавляем перенаправление почты, адресованной для *fakeuser*, какому-нибудь скрипту:

```
$ tail -n 1 /etc/aliases
fakeuser: "| /tmp/fakescript"
```

создаём этот скрипт:

```
$ cat /tmp/fakescript 
#!/bin/bash
cat - >> /tmp/log
```

присваиваем ему биты исполняемости:

```
$ chmod +x /tmp/fakescript
```

и проверяем парой писем:

```
$ echo test | mail -s 'subject 1' fakeuser
$ echo test | mail -s 'subject 2' fakeuser
```

они поступили в файл `/tmp/log`:

```
$ grep '^Subject:' /tmp/log 
Subject: subject 1
Subject: subject 2
```

т.е., в скрипте можно было сделать любую требующуюся обработку этих писем.