# Вызывать php скрипт при появлении нового письма в Exim4

Tags: php, exim4

Необходимо, когда приходит новое письмо на определенный почтовый ящик (ну или хотя бы на любой), вызвать php скрипт, в который передать тело, заголовок письма. Я в обращении с Exim новичок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача заголовков письма в команду . Maildrop or Postfix](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448130/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-maildrop-or-postfix). в частности, обратите внимание на [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448136/178576).

Comment: ваш ответ мне не понятен, я попробовал выполнить команды 
$ tail -n 1 /etc/aliases
fakeuser: "| /tmp/fakescript". Сначала выполняю в консоли
$ tail -n 1 /etc/aliases
Ответ 
roor: <username>
Далее пытаюсь выполнить 
fakeuser: "| /tmp/fakescript"
Ответ
fakeuser:: command not found

Comment: там лишь демонстрация. программа tail всего лишь выводит указанное количество последних строк из указанного файла. подразумевается, что нужная строка уже добавлена в файл `/etc/aliases`. // ещё: с доллара начинаются строки с командами. остальные строки — это вывод этих комманд.

Comment: ещё: программа `cat` выводит всё содержимое указанного файла.

Comment: Понял, благодарю